# $E \subset \mathbb{R}$, $\rho_E :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, where $\rho_E(x) = \inf\{ \mid x - y \mid : y \in E \}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Need to prove this is a continuous function

$E \subset \mathbb{R}$, $\rho_E :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, where $\rho_E(x) = \inf\{ \mid x - y \mid : y \in E \}$

Give some $a,b$ and $\delta > 0$ where $\mid a - b \mid < \delta$ implies $b - \delta < a < b + \delta$ then $\forall y \in E$, $a-y < b-y + \delta$

Now im not sure if constructing a sequence is the way to go but it seems to be the case. so that I can get to $\mid \rho_E(a) - \rho_E(b) \mid \le |a-b| < \delta $ so $\epsilon = \delta $ would give it to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I here give a  proof of a general result:

If $E$ is a non empty subset of a metric space $(X,d)$ then I'll  show that the function $\rho_E:X \to \bf R_{\geq 0}$ defined as  $ \rho _E (x)=d(x,E)=$inf $\{ d(x,y) , y \in E \} $ is continuous.

Because $$| \rho _E(x) - \rho_E(y) | = | d(x,E) - d(y,E) | \leq d(x,y)$$.

This means that $f$ is uniformly continuous (use $\delta = \epsilon$ in any point),which is of course stronger than continuity.

Now for your particular case use $X= \bf R$,and $d(x,y)= \vert x-y \vert$ the usual distance on $ \bf R$